# What is a Tool for Web Page Comparison?

Tags: html, comparison

Given the release of Microsoft Expression's Web 3 SuperPreview (very nice tool BTW), are there any tools that will compare two web addresses against each other? As in a way to compare dev to stage or something like that? Something with an overlay would be very nice.

Comment: You want to do that over http for sites which are not 'owned' by you? Why? And if your own sites, why not using WinDiff or something similar?

Comment: +1 for WinDiff . . . that program has helped me many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want WYSIWYG then there are many options - either use something like:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/compare-web-page-changes-side-by-side/8047/
or two tabs to http://browsershots.org/ where you can again compare outputs (either with graphic software or human eye).